# TinyMCE inside iframe on an iPad

Tags: ipad, jquery-ui, iframe, tinymce

I have an jquery ui dialog that opens up an iframe and a textarea is inside it (email dialog).

When using the iPad to open the dialog, the iframe loads but the TinyMCE script gets only as far as hiding the textarea.

We have textareas that are not in iframes and TinyMCE degrades nicely and doesn't hide the textarea.

How can I make TinyMCE behave the same way inside the iframe?

Comment: Try posting some sample code so we can test